# Custom message for @Security annotation

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I'm trying to use `@Security` annotations for my routes. Like this:

```
/**
 * @return Response
 * @Route("/action")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 * @Template()
 */
public function someAction()
{
    return array();
}
```

When the security restriction fires an exception, I get the message `Expression "has_role('ROLE_USER')" denied access`.

This is not acceptable to be shown to the end user, so I'm trying to find a way to customize the message for annotation.

Simple workaround is to not to use `@Secutity` annotations and write code like these:

```
/**
 * @return Response
 * @Route("/action")
 * 
 * @Template()
 */
public function someAction()
{
    if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('You have to be logged in in order to use this feature');
    }

    return array();
}
```

But this is less convenient and less readable.

Is it possible to write custom message to `@Security` annotations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As soon as I realized that this is not possible, I have made a [pull request](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/pull/311) to the `Sensio FrameworkExtra Bundle` to make this possible.

This PR allows to customize displayed message by specifying the message parameter like

```
@Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')",message="You have to be logged in")
```

Comment: So why did you close the PR? It was a good one, still receveing upvotes after closing. Please consider re-opening it.

Comment: Well, actually because one year passed without any maintainers comment, but the PR gone out of sync and I've seen no purpose to maintain it.