# Symfony 3: Customize the template for @Secutity annotation exceptions

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to customize the twig template for errors thrown on `@Security("has_role('CUSTOM_ADMIN')")`

I have already seen [a similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328054/custom-message-for-security-annotation) but for Symfony 2.

I think that `@Security` annotation logic bypasses the Twig template overriding because I have followed the directions on the official docs about [customizing error pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html) but those template files are getting ignored and i just get the default Symfony exception page with:

`Expression "has_role('CUSTOM_ADMIN')" denied access.`

Am I missing something?

Comment: While you're in the development environment, Symfony shows the big exception page instead of your shiny new customized error page. Are you sure testing it in prod env? http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development

Comment: @yceruto This works, please add your comment as an answer so i can make it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're in the development environment, Symfony shows the big *exception* page instead of your shiny new customized error page. So, how can you see what it looks like and debug it?

Fortunately, the default `ExceptionController` allows you to preview your error pages during development.

To use this feature, you need to have a definition in your `routing_dev.yml` file like so:

```
# app/config/routing_dev.yml
_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error
```

If you're coming from an older version of Symfony, you might need to add this to your routing_dev.yml file. If you're starting from scratch, the Symfony Standard Edition already contains it for you.

With this route added, you can use URLs like:

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php/_error/{statusCode}
http://localhost/app_dev.php/_error/{statusCode}.{format}
```

to preview the error page for a given status code as HTML or for a given status code and format.

Ref: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development